# BCrypt - is known prefix a vulnerability?

Tags: bcrypt

I'm generating API tokens for my web app. Let's say, 30 symbols in length.

To protect against database leaks, I'd like to store them in encrypted form. BCrypt, because that's the easiest with the framework I'm using.

Since every user might have many tokens, for their convenience I'd like to have the first few symbols of the token available, so that they can, for example see that token `qwert...` was generated last month, and last used today, but `asdfg...` has not yet been used.

If I store first 5 symbols of the token in plain text, next to the BCrypt-ed form of the full token, do I have:

1. Effectively a 25 symbol token, but still reasonably secure system;

or

2. Security theater, because knowing the plaintext prefix enables attacker to easily force the whole token open?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Don't BCrypt API tokens; Use SHA256.

---

No, knowing the prefix (or any substring) doesn't weaken the BCrypt hash, beyond the obvious fact that you have reduced the difficulty of a bruteforce attack by shrinking the keyspace.

But regardless, this is a misapplication of BCrypt. BCrypt is for hashing short, poor quality, user-generated passwords, which are tested *one time* on login, when you can afford the relatively expensive BCrypt comparison.

Long, strongly random tokens don't need the protection BCrypt provides, and it is an egregious waste of computing resources to pay the cost of a BCrypt comparison on *every API request your server handles*. Your entire API winds up with awful response times for no good reason.

Use SHA256 or SHA512 for hashing tokens.